# jquery - Getting a DOM path as a string of integers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
      <d>
      <e>
        <f>
</root>
```

I want to attach the onclick method of f to make an AJAX request such that it sends to the server, 0020

This effectively encodes the path as a string

Any easy means to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the [`$.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) of the current element and append the [`$.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of each to an array:

```
var dompath = [];

$(".some-element").parentsUntil(".some-other-selector").each(function () {
    dompath.push($(this).index());
});

dompath = dompath.join("").reverse();
```

You'll then need to reverse the path to get the proper order; since otherwise you'd end up with `0200`, which won't be found.

Comment: I see, and then basically if I know my parent node that I want to terminate on, I check for that in the function for each parent? I don't want to go all the way to html element, only some element.

Comment: Exactly. I've edited the answer to provide that functionality.

Comment: @FelixKling; and I saw that function just a few moments ago, too!